# Bukkit reset block after a few seconds

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

If a block is placed/destroyed or exploded, the block is saved and after a few seconds it will be placed at the same location and as the same material.

Can someone explain me how I could do it?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly ? What did you tried ? Show your code, and check [ask]

Answer (score 0):

All things in Bukkit like that are based on `Event`s. Almost everything that can happen in Minecraft triggers an event to happen which we can then interact with using Bukkit.

For your situation, you'll need to use [`BlockBreakEvent`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/block/BlockBreakEvent.html) and [`BlockPlaceEvent`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/block/BlockPlaceEvent.html).

Two pages that will help you get started with this:

- https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/using-the-event-api/
- https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/scheduler-programming/